# Error: IO_ERROR : java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server

Tags: hadoop, oozie, hadoop2, ambari

I am new to oozie and was following [this](https://blogs.oracle.com/datawarehousing/entry/building_simple_workflows_in_oozie) for my first oozie hive job.
As per given in tutorial ,i made following files in a directory:

1. hive-default.xml
2. hive_job1.hql
3. job.properties
4. workflow.xml

But when i run this command:

```
 oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/ -config  /home/ec2-user/ankit/oozie_job1/job.properties -submit
```

I get following error:

> Error: IO_ERROR : java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server. No of retries = 1. Exception = Could not authenticate, Authentication failed, status: 404, message: Not Found

I tried finding solution for this on internet ,but none solved the problem.(Might have missed something)

Please let me know where i am going wrong and what additional information will be required more from my side to understand the problem.

Answer (score 3):

The error is because of the incorrect value for `-oozie` parameter. You forgot to add the `oozie` in the end.  It should be `-oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie`

```
 oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config  /home/ec2-user/ankit/oozie_job1/job.properties -submit
```

Comment: After running this command i get following error:
"Error: E0501 : E0501: Could not perform authorization operation, Call From ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx/xx.xx.xx.xx to localhost:8020 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"

Comment: Add the configuration provided by @NishuTayal.

Comment: I did the changes and restarted hadoop cluster.But after that i get this problem:
"Error: IO_ERROR : java.io.IOException: Error while connecting Oozie server. No of retries = 4. Exception = Connection refused"
I am using ambari and its been installed on ec2 instance.

Comment: Can you check the oozie logs at `/var/log/oozie/`? May be the server is not even running?

Answer (score 1):

Please try setting following properties in core-site.xml:

```
 <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
    <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
```

where `*` represents to all users.

Restart the hadoop cluster after making above changes.

Comment: I did the changes as above but it throws this error now :"Error: E0708 : E0708: Invalid transition, node [Oozie_test] transition [Tester]"